# Display time in android app from API

Tags: android, api, tracking

Working on android application of bus tracking. API gives data of current bus location, last location and expected location with time in HH:MM:SS. I am displaying station name and time from API which refreshes every 3 minutes. 
The devices with version 6.0.x displays system time whereas other devices displays from API.

Comment: you are aware of network request libraries ?

Comment: i mean volley or retrofit ?

Comment: @Dhara add your code snippet so you can get exact solution

Comment: the problem is in your code.

Comment: is your target version 23.0 x or not?

Comment: provide code where u fetch time and set @Dhara